Is there a formula that describes multiple normal distributions?
Sorry, I'm not very savvy with statistics (yet), and have been stumped by this problem for a couple weeks - getting lost in all the incredible depth on the topic!
I have a piece of code that will randomly spit out values according to specified a normal distribution (mean & STD). However, it also randomizes between 3 different normal distributions. I tried averaging the mean, and using the root mean square of the STD as suggested here.
$$
\hat{\mu}=\frac{\hat{\mu}_{X}+\hat{\mu}_{Y}}{2}\text{ and }\hat{\sigma}^{2}=\frac{\hat{\sigma}_{X}^{2}+\hat{\sigma}_{Y}^{2}}{2}.
$$
But I'm like 90% sure I'm not supposed to be using this for my situation, as the resulting unified normal distribution is suggesting relatively common actual occurrences are supposed to be super rare.
Maybe I'm supposed to be looking for something more like a multimodal distribution? One of my main goals is to be able to know the probability of a particular value given several equally probable normal deviations.
Thank you so much in advance for any assistance!

Three distributions aren't going to average out to a normal.  Why not use the distribution as it stands?  To get the probability that a sample lies in some interval $[a,b]$, work that out for each of the three underlying normals and average.

@lulu - Interesting, thank you! So if a particular value has a 5% probability on one distribution, 8% on second, and 17% on the third, do you know if it would just be a simple average of 10%?

Well...these are continuous distributions, so each value has probability $0$.  That's why I spoke of ranges.  But, basically, yes.  You have three paths toward landing in the given range and it's equally likely that you are on any one of the paths, so you just average.
